# Bibliography style (vancouver)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm quite new with LaTeX, but am trying to write my master's thesis with it.
I'm running into a problem with the bibliography style.

This is what the school asks for the reference style (with the abbreviation of journal names):

> Gibson J.P. (1989) Selection strategies and artificial evolution.
>   Theor.
>          Appl. Genet. 78,87-92.

And in the text, the citation has to be "author, year" form.
I think that it's Vancouver style without numeration.

I used the  `natbib` package.

However, when I downloaded the Vancouver `.bst` file from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver)
after compiling, I cannot get the abbreviation of the  Journal name.

The `.bst` file I downloaded from [Elsevier](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/the-elsarticle-latex-document-class) doesn't work either.

Does anybody have any ideas about how I can  abbreviate journal names?

Comment: There are various ways to do this.  See [Overriding fields in a bibtex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107838/2693) for some good suggestions.

Comment: If the answers in the linked question are sufficient for you, we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Alan I don't know why. I still can't get my journal name abbreviated. I even tried custom bib several time, but still can't make it.

Comment: @Zih-Hua Without seeing what you've now tried, it's hard to tell what the problem is.  Did you use the procedure outlined in the other question?  If so, post a link your modified `.bib` file, and post a minimal document that shows the problem.  Do you get abbreviated names with the `.bst` file I created?

Comment: @Alan I did get abbreviated names with the .bst file you provided., but it abbreviated journals with one word like Nature as well. I also have to find a way to modify the author initials to meet my request. Anyway, it did work with the abbreviation issue. Here's the .bst file I created using custum-bib, but I can't get abbreviated names. Can somebody help this one out? https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwigf98fob99ggt/thesis.bst

Comment: Here's the minimal document                         \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[warnundef]{jabbrv}
\usepackage[round, colon]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{thesis}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}

Comment: Does the `.bst` file you created do everything else you want except for abbreviate the journal names? (i.e. does it do what you want with author names?)  If so, I can take a look at it to see what the problem is with abbreviating the journal names.  But if it still needs some work, then that may be another question.

Comment: @Alan Yes, the .bst file I created meets all the requests expect for abbreviation of the journal names. Would you please have a look at it? I tried several times and still can't get it. I'm wondering if it is the problem of "stored journal name". I've tried every option, but all give the same results. Or should I use other package as well?

Comment: @zih-hua I've added a full answer on how to modify your custom-bib generated file.  Hopefully this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion in the comments, you created a new `.bst` file using the `custom-bib` package.  This `.bst` file then needs to be modified to be used with the `jabbrv` package.

It seems that the `.bib` files created by `custom-bib` package are a bit more sophisticated than the basic `.bst` files assumed by the package, and the modification suggested in the package web site doesn't work.  Thanks to some discussion in chat with Joseph Wright, here's a modified function that works:

```
FUNCTION {format.journal}
{journal duplicate$ empty$
  'pop$
  {
    "\JournalTitle{" swap$ * "}" *
    emphasize
    output
  }
if$
}
```

This function is added to the `.bst` file and the following line in the `{article}` function of the `.bst` file

```
journal "journal" output.check
```

is changed to

format.journal "journal" output.check

Name the new `.bst` file `jabbrv_thesis`.  I've put a copy here:

[Modified .bst file](http://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/jabbrv_thesis.bst)

Now you can use the `jabbrv` package to do the abbreviations.  To do this you use:

```
\usepackage[warnundef]{jabbrv}
\bibliographystyle{jabbrv_thesis}
```

If there are particular journal names that you *don't* want abbreviated (e.g. *Nature*) then you need to edit the `jabbrv-ltwa-en.ldf` file (located in the `jabbrv` folder) and comment out the `\DefineJournalAbbreviation` lines for those names.  If there words that aren't abbreviated, but should be, (these will show up in the warnings) then you need to add lines like the following to your document.

```
\DefineJournalAbbreviation{<full name>}{<abbreviation>} % no final '.'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did get the abbreviation. However, I got another problem. I got author names followed by the full journal name which didn't happen with the original thesis.bst file I created. I tried to get rid of it, but can't find the way. Here's an example: Trujillo A.J., Casals I., Guamis B. (2000) Journal of Chromatography. A.  Analysis of major ovine milk proteins by reversed-phase high-performance liquid chromatography and flow injection analysis with electrospray ionization mass spectrometry., J. Chromatogr. A. 870,
371–80.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a bibstyle file **vancouver-authoryear.bst** that allows you to use `natbib` style *`authoryear`* citations with `vancouver` style references.

[Please see this for my previous post on the steps to follow to get this done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266949/82723)

Sample output:

[image]